# Is this PDO code valid?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

i have extracted this snippet from my code as im concerned that there is a better way to do this. I'm hoping someone can help me or point me in the right direction.

basically this code checks numerous tables in a database and checks if the result returns or not.

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT email FROM 1table WHERE email = :email'); 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT email FROM 2table WHERE email = :email');
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT email FROM 3table WHERE email = :email'); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->execute();
    if($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) > 0){
```

Is there a better way? or a more productive way, which could tell me what table the result was found in?

Comment: You keep overwriting your `$stmt` variable, so the only query to go ahead (this is to my experience) is the last

Comment: @WesleySchleumer could `UNION` tell me which table contained the result?

Comment: Create an pseudo column which will tell you from where did it comes. `SELECT email, "3table" as "container"`...

Comment: thanks! I'll take a look at some tutorials on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of previous anwsers shows to you how to know which talbe is the data from. So, if this is relevant, this is the correct `UNION`

```
$sql  = "SELECT email, '1table' as fromTable  FROM 1table WHERE email = :email"; 
$sql .= " UNION ALL"; 
$sql .= " SELECT email, '2table' FROM 2table WHERE email = :email"; 
$sql .= " UNION ALL"; 
$sql .= " SELECT email, '3table' FROM 3table WHERE email = :email";
```

Comment: can you explain how i would know where the result has come from? `fromTable` would hold it, but how would i check?

Comment: `$fieldArr = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` this will give an associative array with all fields, or false if there are no more rows to fetch

Comment: worked fantastically! However, it fails to return multiple instances in the array, this is not essential for me so this is the best way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

It's valid PHP but your logic is not valid:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT email FROM 1table WHERE email = :email'); 
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT email FROM 2table WHERE email = :email');
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT email FROM 3table WHERE email = :email');
```

You keep overwriting `$stmt` with a new value. Which means that `$stmt` will only contains the last prepare statement.

You can take a look at `UNION` and modify your code as following:

```
$sql = '(SELECT email FROM 1table WHERE email = :email)'; 
$sql .= 'UNION ALL'; 
$sql .= '(SELECT email FROM 2table WHERE email = :email)'; 
$sql .= 'UNION ALL'; 
$sql .= '(SELECT email FROM 3table WHERE email = :email)'; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

Comment: so perhaps one at a time? executing after each to see if the result exists? or is that too time consuming?

Answer (score 1):

This would only use the last query. You can do this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('
    (SELECT email FROM 1table WHERE email = :email)
    union all
    (SELECT email FROM 2table WHERE email = :email)
    union all
    (SELECT email FROM 3table WHERE email = :email)');
```